# Clipping multiple rasters based on their overlapping area ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, landsat, overlapping-features

I have Landsat Collection 1 Surface Reflectance NDVI images.  I would like to do pixel based time-series analysis and I need all images to be in the same dimension corresponding to the same area. So I would like to clip all my raster images based on their overlapping area.

Is there a way to define the overlapping area of all images and clip regarding this overlapping area in ArcMap 10.3?

Comment: Do you want the rasters to have the same extent or remove all areas where some raster dont overlap?

Comment: I want to achieve both at the same time. When the non-overlaping areas are removed, all images will correspond to the same area and will have the same extent. So when I want to check for example row 5 column 10, it will correspond to the same coordinates in all images and I can perform pixel based time-analysis.

Comment: Simply run cell statistics on all of them. Convert output to polygon. Use it a environment extent, use raster as mask. If CellStatistics​ won't work, multiply them.

Answer (score 1):

You should definietely use ModelBuilder. First - put all Your rasters into one folder. Turn on ModelBuilder in ArcMap and select option "Rasters" from Insert > Iterators.

[image]

This tool takes all raster files in defined catalog or database. You can type something in 'Wildcard' if they have common name.

[image]

Then You shall put "Extract by mask" tool to Your model and connect it to "Iterate Raster":

[image]

This simple model takes raster from directory one by one and it's clipping them with feature You've selected in "Extract by mask" tool.

Comment: And what should be used as extacting feature? Your answer is not complete

Comment: When you use "Extract by mask" tool and choose one of the images as "input raster or feature mask data" the resulting images won't correspond to the same geographical area as different parts of the geo-referenced images overlay with the chosen input raster mask data. Meaning the extend of the images and the corresponding geographical area will be different. One way to solve this can be using the overlapping image of the first 2 images as an input mask for the extraction of the 3rd image. Then using this result for the extraction of the 4th image. But I can't use 2 iterations in one model.

Answer (score 1):

The mosaicked image displayed from a mosaic dataset can be created from a number of input rasters that are often overlapping. The mosaic method defines how the mosaicked image is created from these input rasters.

For example, when using the By Attribute method, the values in an attribute field are used to sort the images, and when using Closest to Center, the image closest to the center of the display is positioned as the top image in the mosaic. Additionally, the mosaic operator allows you to define how to resolve the overlapping cells, such as choosing a blending operation.

When working with the mosaic dataset, there are two places to modify the mosaic method. If you're editing the mosaic dataset and you need to set the default mosaic method (or limit the options), you will modify the mosaic dataset properties. This permanently alters the mosaic dataset. However, if you're viewing the mosaic dataset as a data source and not modifying it for the benefit of others, you can change the mosaic method from the Image layer. This way, you only impact your display and do not permanently impact others when viewing or accessing the mosaic dataset.

For more info please click on this link
[Understanding the mosaicking rules for a mosaic dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/understanding-the-mosaicking-rules-for-a-mosaic-dataset.htm)

[Clip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm)